# How to classify a "Trip" from multiple GPS pings of each Unique ID?

Tags: dataset, data-mining, geospatial

I have a huge file of lat/long & timestamp data from vehicles and I need to identify "Trips" from these multiple pings of Each vehicle ID. Trips have a "Start" & "end". Every vehicle has UID in the dataset & associated lat-long with timestamp. I am finding it very difficult to detect a trip while excluding outliers like traffic jams and traffic stops

Can you help me understand - how to identify & classify a "Trips"? while excluding false positives like "Traffic stops". (if there are quick ways like any libraries or APIs would be helpful)

Comment: why not looking at difference in timestamps ?

Comment: @Icmorin, Just looking at timestamps only will not help... the pings are recorded every 30 seconds... so from all the multiple pings ... how do I classify a "stop" & "Start."...??